# How to apply class to header title with span tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this title in my header section:

```
 <header>
     <div class="container">
         <div>
             <h1>Salon <span class="test">Le Zen</span></h1>
         </div>
```

In my css file, I have this:

```
.test{
    color:aqua
}
```

This class work for div tags in my body section of my HTML file, but for my title (within the same HTML file)... nothing! :(

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the CSS file containing that class BEFORE your header?

Comment: Which title do you mean? If I put that code in a snippet, the "Le Zen" part turns an aqua color.. please share more of your code. Also you may want to consider adding the css to the h1 property, instead of a span, if you want the whole title to turn aqua

Comment: Ouuuffff !  I found my horrible error!!!  Thanks Rachel!  I did mixed up the <title> in the header section with the <h1> tags.  So in resume I tried to put style in a title instead of my header. The joy of learning new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use a selector with a higher *specifity*, like

```
h1 > span.test { color:aqua }
```

or even

```
.container h1 > span.test { color:aqua }
```

Answer (score -1):

It works herehttps://jsfiddle.net/z8xf56u4/

Check your spelling that might be it.
If it is not you can copy both files here and I will check if there is a problem